# Frozen Title Attribute in Opengraph Debugger

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm receiving an error in the object debugger that states:

> Attempted Frozen Title Change It appears that you are trying to change
>   the property og:title from Home to [the title] If so, you are not allowed to
>   for this object because too many actions have been published against
>   it.

It's scraping the tag:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="[the title]" />
```

The [the title] value is what I want the title to appear as - however, the title is simply populating as 'Home' in the debugger.

So two questions:

1) How can I 'unfreeze' this property/is this possible?

2) How can I prevent this happening in the future?

Thank you in advance.