# Facebook issue: Attempted Frozen Title Change

Tags: angularjs, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm attempting to change the Facebook open graph og:title meta tag value for my blog. I get a Frozen Title Attribute error in the open graph URL debugger. However, no one's shared the site on Facebook yet (I only tested the old one in the debugger). To further complicate things, the blog is a Single Page App in Angular, and so I can't have a separate title for each bog post. I anticipate a need to change the title each time I share a new blog post.

I know this has been posted elsewhere ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25205982/warning-attempted-frozen-title-change), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19413613/frozen-title-attribute-in-opengraph-debugger)), but the only answer seems to try to get a Facebook developer's help (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25957642/attempted-frozen-title-change-any-fb-developers)). Let me know if you're one and if you can help!

Answer (score 1):

This will not be possible. It's a preventative measure against owners changing titles. Seeing that you want this changed more than once, I doubt you will get the support you need.

The only times I have seen requests carried out are under very rare unforeseen circumstances. The scenario you presented doesn't sound like this as you are intentionally wanting to change the title on a continuous basis. This will affect all previously submitted links, thus why title was frozen.

If you *do* think there is more to this issue, file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs but as I said, it's highly unlikely you will get it changed it's even more highly unlikely that you will get changed on a continuous basis.